# How to vertically align some text inside css3 circles?

Tags: html, css, web

I've got those three inline elements here that I am trying to make a circle out of it with css3, but the problem is when I add the css3 style the text inside the circle is not vertically aligned, so my question is how do i make sure that no matter font-size/ family/ browser/ font size inside the circle will be verticaly aligned ?!

```css
.num {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #dd5638;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="num">
      <div class="num-content">
        41, 000+ <span>jobs</span>
      </div>
      <!--num content-->
    </div>
    <!--num-->
  </div>
  <!--col-->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="num">
      <div class="num-content">
        56 <span>countries</span>
      </div>
      <!--num content-->
    </div>
    <!--num-->
  </div>
  <!--col-->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="num">
      <div class="num-content">
        8 <span>programs</span>
      </div>
      <!--num content-->
    </div>
    <!--num-->
  </div>
  <!--col-->
</div>
<!--row-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the .num div element `position: relative;` then absolutely position .num-content as a forced centered div

```
.num-content
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
.num{
font-size: 26px;
line-height: 26px;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
height: 140px;
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
background: #dd5638;
-webkit-border-radius:100%;
-moz-border-radius:100%;
border-radius: 100%;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
position:relative;
}

.num-content
{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="num">
         <div class="num-content">
            <span>41,000+ jobs</span>
         </div>
         <!--num content-->
      </div>
      <!--num-->
   </div>
   <!--col-->
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="num">
         <div class="num-content">
            <span>56 countries</span>
         </div>
         <!--num content-->
      </div>
      <!--num-->
   </div>
   <!--col-->
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="num">
         <div class="num-content">
            <span>8 programs</span>
         </div>
         <!--num content-->
      </div>
      <!--num-->
   </div>
   <!--col-->
</div>
<!--row-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the flex layout and decrease a bit font-size:

```css
.num {
  font-size: 25px;/* sized down 30 to 25 */
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #dd5638;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  display:flex;/* added */
  flex-flow:column;/* added */
  justify-content:center;/* added */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="num">
      <div class="num-content">
        41, 000+ <span>jobs</span>
      </div>
      <!--num content-->
    </div>
    <!--num-->
  </div>
  <!--col-->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="num">
      <div class="num-content">
        56 <span>countries</span>
      </div>
      <!--num content-->
    </div>
    <!--num-->
  </div>
  <!--col-->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="num">
      <div class="num-content">
        8 <span>programs</span>
      </div>
      <!--num content-->
    </div>
    <!--num-->
  </div>
  <!--col-->
</div>
<!--row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to vertically align text is to make the content `display: table-cell`, then `vertical-align` it to the `middle`. In your case:

```css
.num .num-content{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, in order for this to work, the parent element MUST use `display: table`. That should do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually just add even padding all the way around the child, and if the child is text, I set the line-height to match the font size.

This allows you to easily add media queries to the circle to make them smaller/larger just by changing a single value - padding. Also, not very much CSS needed.

```
   <div class="circle">
      <div class="child">8</div>
   </div>

  .circle{
    background:#000;
    border-radius:50%;
 }

  .child{
     padding:20px;
     font-size:1em;
     line-height:1em;
     color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is the best way.

```
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
```

Do not do the table method that someone suggested elsewhere. Flex is the best answer here.